# Python function to parse String to 1. Int, 2. Float or 3. String (unchanged)

Tags: python

How to write a Python function that take one String argument and return following three type of output types depending on input value

```py
def parseValue(v):
...
```

For example:

"123.45" -> parseValue("123.45") -> 123.45 (float)

"12345" -> parseValue("12345") -> 12345 (int)

"-23" -> parseValue("-23") -> -23 (int)

"Florida" -> parseValue("Florida") -> Florida (String and kept the input unchanged)

"0.12" -> parseValue("0.12") -> 0.12 (float)

"0010" -> parseValue("0010") -> "0010" keep it as string since this could be a code that require leading zeros

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from typing import Union

def parse_value(val: str) -> Union[float, int, str]:
  try:
    res = float(val)
    if res.is_integer():
      res = int(res)
    if not val.startswith('0') or '.' in val:
      return res
  except ValueError:
    pass
  return val
```

```
>>> parse_value('123.45')
123.45
>>> parse_value('12345')
12345
>>> parse_value('-23')
-23
>>> parse_value('Florida')
'Florida'
>>> parse_value('0.12')
0.12
>>> parse_value('0010')
'0010'
>>> parse_value('0000')
'0000'
```

Comment: Is this is a valid syntax in Python3?
`def parse_value(val: str) -> float | int | str:`

I am getting this error
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type' `

Python version I am using is: Python 3.9.6

Comment: @TW2021, i'm sorry for this, i'm using 3.10.0rc2 (release candidate version), and already got used to these type definitions. For 3.9.6 it will be `typing.Union[float, int, str]`

Comment: Adam thanks for the sample function, it work great except for this user case ` parse_value('0000')` return int 0, I would expect it to be return string '0000'.

Comment: @TW2021 , updated to suit your expectations

Comment: Adam, this is working great, thank you!